# Can't copy files between pc and usb device

Tags: windows-xp, windows-explorer, usb-storage

I used to be able to copy/move files between my Samsung s3 and pc (windows xp) when one day it stopped doing that. 
I can see the files on my phone through windows file explorer but when I move files from pc to phone a mssg pops up 'device has been disconnected' ... from phone to pc just does nothing. I can highlight (select) the files but can't do any movement with them. Also can't open the files (when double clicking on them). However don't have any issues with usb flash drives .. they behave as expected. 
When I plug the phone in another pc then works fine. 
The other day I tried copying images from my camera to pc and that also didn't work anymore (it used to) ... same behaviour as the phone. 
What can it be ? 
Thanks in advance.
Alex

Answer (score 0):

First guess is the USB cord/hub/port is going bad. Try different cords & hubs & ports.

Or, maybe the phone has updated recently & no longer works properly with Windows XP. It is quite old (released 2001) and extended support for Windows XP ended on April 8, 2014 [[1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_XP), even though it appears to be the [4th most popular Windows version](http://gs.statcounter.com/windows-version-market-share/desktop/worldwide/#monthly-201603-201708) still in August 2017.

Consider switching to a newer supported OS is recommended, a nice Linux or a newer Windows. With no more Windows XP support, every day is now "zero day" for new exploits.

Answer (score 0):

Same happens to me when I connect an USB-powered external hard drive or an MP3 player to a USB port with low power. I'm also using Windows XP SP3. I would suggest you trying it in a different USB port on your PC. My best advice is to try all the USB ports you have on your PC. Another to try is to have the phone fully charged before connecting. Then it might not start charging and cause a power drain on your USB port.

If low power turns out to be the problem, you might want to get a **Dual Input USB Cable** and plug the USB connector of your Samsung S3 into that. Find more details about them on Google. They're neat.

Please don't listen to people who try to scare you into upgrading. You are safe to stay with Windows XP if you have a decent firewall and avoid malicious sites while browsing the web.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your input.. I still haven't resolved my issue. I had the opportunity to plug my phone into another win xp pc .. and viola it worked.. so not a software version incompatibility.  Then it struck me .. a while back I uninstalled my old Kodak camera software (as I don't have the camera anymore). Perhaps since then (difficult to tell) the generic drivers regarding data transfer between usb devices got uninstalled .. could explain it currently behaving oddly. Hence the next question: how do I uninstall mass media storage drivers and reinstall new? I recall mssgs in the task bar when I plugged my phone into the other win xp pc 'detecting new device ..  installing drivers' .. how can I replicate this again on my pc.? 
Thanks